# Print all perfect numbers less than N

Tags: python

I am trying to print all perfect numbers lesser than an integer, but I am not sure how to do it. Could you help me, please? When I execute the code, it writes `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`.

My code:

```
n = input() 
w = int(n) - 1
i = 0
a = 0
z = 0
list = []
for w in range(w, 1):
    for i in range(w, 2):
        if w % i == 0:
            a = int(w / i)
            z = z + a
    if z == w:
        list.append(w)
print(list)
```

> What is a perfect number?

In number theory, a perfect number is a positive integer that is equal to the sum of its positive divisors, excluding the number itself.

Comment: Two problems with the question:
#1 What is a perfect number
#2 What do you type for input

Comment: Never override python builtin names: i.e. don't do `list = []`

Comment: also don't use existing variables as loop variables

Comment: and also `a` and `i`don't have to be defined as `0`

Comment: It would be helpful if you added some comments to your code to help us understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
n = input('Enter the integer:') 
w = int(n) - 1
l = [] # creating an empty list 'l'
for i in range(w, 0, -1): # Runs the loop for all integers below n and greater than 0. 
  s = 0 # Set the sum to 0. 
  for j in range(i,0, -1): # Runs the loop till 0 to check for all divisors
    if i % j == 0 and j!= i: # If the number is a divisor of 'i' and not equal to the 'i' itself. 
      s = s + j # Then add the divisor to the sum
  if s == i: # If sum is equal to the number 'i'
    l.append(i) # Then add the number 'i' to the list 'l'
print(l)
```

Output:

```
Enter the integer:10000
[8128, 496, 28, 6]
```

### What you were doing wrong?

1. Naming a list by a Python keyword is a bad practice and should be avoided! You named the list by the name `list` which is a keyword in Python.
2. You were using the same variable names for different tasks such as `w` for denoting integer less than `n` and also range in for loop. This should be avoided too!
3. Idk, why you were using the variable `a` but there's no need to initialize variables with `0` if you are using as `range in for loop`.
4. You were running the for loop till `1` instead should run it `0`.
5. You were not setting the sum to zero at every integer.

Comment: Some reasons *might* be (can't say for sure): The algorithm is slow, unnecessarily complex, verbose and inefficient.  (I say this only because you asked, and not to be critical.)  :-)

Comment: @S3DEV Thanks for replying. I get that my approach is not efficient but OP didn't ask for that. They asked why and how to do it and not in the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a *very* simple implementation of the perfect numbers algorithm:

```
def isperfect(n: int) -> bool:
    """Test if a number is perfect."""
    sum_ = sum(i for i in range(1, n//2+1) if not n % i)
    return sum_ == n

n = int(input('Enter a positive integer: '))
p = [i for i in range(1, n) if isperfect(i)]
```

Output:

```
Enter a positive integer: 10000

print('Perfect numbers:', *p)
Perfect numbers:  6 28 496 8128
```

---

Explanation:

1. The `isperfect` function is used to test whether `n` is perfect. Efficiency is gained by only testing numbers <= n/2.
2. Capture the user's requested integer.
3. Using list comprehension, iterate the range of values (N-1) and test if each is perfect.
4. The perfect numbers are captured and stored into the `p` variable as a `list`.

Comment: Why turn perfectly fine `True`/`False` into `1`/`0`?

Comment: Preference really, a lot of my work is in C. So just a simplistic carryover.  (Although `bool` *is* more memory efficient.)